# Likelihood ratio test: train two models or one?

Tags: likelihood-ratio

I have a dataset with features A, B and C and an output label D. I want to perform the likelihood ratio test to see if feature C contributes to the performance of a regression model.

Do I:

- train two models $M_1$ and $M_2$, one using features A B C, one using only features A B, and perform the test using those two models (with weights $\theta_{A,B}$ and bias $\theta_0$ being different to a certain extent between the two models, *i.e.* $\theta_A^{M_1}\neq\theta_A^{M_2}$, $\theta_B^{M_1}\neq\theta_B^{M_2}$ and $\theta_0^{M_1}\neq\theta_0^{M_2}$)

OR

- train one model $M$ using A B C, then perform the test using this model and a model $M_{\theta_C=0}$ where the weight for C is set to zero (that is a model that does not take features C into account but with the two models having the same weights and biases, *i.e.* $\theta_A^{M}=\theta_A^{M_{\theta_C=0}}$, $\theta_B^{M}=\theta_B^{M_{\theta_C=0}}$ and $\theta_0^{M_1}=\theta_0^{M_2}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the first option.

In the second option, you force the $C$ parameter to be $0$ without letting the other parameters compensate for the fact that this might be an awful value. You want nested models, not two different estimators of the same model (where one estimator takes the MLE and the sets one of the components to zero).

In technical language, option #1 is what gives the asymptotic $\chi^2$ distribution with the claimed degrees of freedom. I’d be curious what a simulation reveals to be the distribution under the null hypothesis if you create the test statistic using option #2.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Also curious how these methods would compare, I'll put your last simulation suggestion on my to-try list.

Answer (score 0):

For doing likelihood ratio tests, ANOVA, or AIC value comparisons, your models need to be nested.

If this is the case, one way you could answer your question is to start with your most complex model (aka use all explanatory variables), and using a reverse model selection method, continue to your simplest model.

Finally, run either (or all) a likelihood ratio test, ANOVA between models, or compare AIC values. The result(s) from any of the above tests can help you decide which model to keep.